# Runtime error reporting missing accept attribute

Tags: python, pyqt4

I am working with python.When i try to run my DlgDbError.py file,it gives me error saying:

```
File "C:\rt_sql_layer\ui\DlgDbError_ui.py", line 47, in setupUi
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox, QtCore.SIGNAL("accepted()"), DlgDbError.accept)
AttributeError: 'DlgDbError' object has no attribute 'accept'
```

but buttonbox has accept method..what can be the problem??

Comment: `'DlgDbError' object has no attribute 'accept'`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error isn't in your `DlgDbError.py` file, it's in the `DlgDbError_ui.py` module that you created with `pyuic4`.

This module will contain a `Ui_DlgDbError` class with a `setupUi` method. This method has a single argument (named `DlgDbError`), which takes an instance of the main form class that you created in Qt Designer (i.e. the one also named `DlgDbError`).

The `setupUi` method is expecting the `DlgDbError` object to have an `accept()` slot, which probably means it should be a subclass of `QDialog`.

Obviously, you are not passing a subclass of `QDialog` to `setupUi`, and so you are getting an `AttributeError`.

You probably need to do something like this:

```
from DlgDbError_ui import Ui_DlgDbError

class MyDlgDbError(Ui_DlgDbError):
    def __init__(self, parent=None)
        self.dialog = QtGui.QDialog(parent)
        self.setupUi(self.dialog)
        ...
```

Comment: i modified the code...but  if i write self.setupUi(self.dialog) then it displays just plain normal window...and error remains...if i comment it then it works fine...

Comment: @poonam. Are you editing the `DlgDbError_ui.py` file that `pyuic4` generates? You should _never_ do that. If you don't call `setupUi`, then, despite what you say, it won't work at all. If you do things right, using a module generated by `pyuic4` is _very_ easy. So my best guess is that you are doing something different that you're not telling us about ;-) The only other thing I can think of is that you have made changes in Qt Designer, but forgotten to re-generate the python module using `pyuic4`.

Comment: I am not editing  DlgDbError_ui.py file..i did in DlgDbError.py file. (code file)...and i converted .ui to .py using pyuic4 compiler too..but when i run it,blank window comes..

Comment: @poonam. Okay. What widgets does your `Ui_DlgDbError` form contain? Your problem is probably simple to fix, but it's hard to help further without seeing the `ui` file. Can you put it up on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)?

Comment: :i did it..i made slot of close button on form as close() instead of accept() and reject().

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it should be `self.buttonBox.accept` instead of `DlgDbError.accept` then?

Answer (score 1):

Should the line be :

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("accepted()")), DlgDbError.accept)
```

i.e. QtCore.SIGNAL("accepted()") should actually be  QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("accepted()"))

Where :

```
_fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
```

Comment: I tried even  QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("accepted()")), DlgDbError.accept)....it gives same error.. my database is in utf8 format..

Comment: `_fromUtf8` is an internal method generated by `pyuic4`. It either does nothing, or, in certain circumstances, it simply converts Python strings to Qt strings. It has no relevance to the question, and there is _never_ any reason to use it in your own code.